# jQuery: Issues with sub menu after mouseout

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I have a submenu that slides in and out on hover. See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K5P9Z/108/).

I have used hover() inside hover(). When I hover on `Test 1`, it slides in the content for submenu. When I hover on the submenu, I want to keep it opened. In the fiddle, this seems to work for Test 1. However, when I mouseout from Test 1 and hover on Test 2, the submenu does not slide out. Also when I mouseout from Test 1 (out of the screen), it still keeps showing the submenu.

How can I fix this and make this code more elegant?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="test1"><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="test2"><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="test3"><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content-area">
    <div id="test1-content">This is test 1 submenu</div>
    <div id="test2-content">This is test 2 submenu</div>
    <div id="test3-content">This is test 3 submenu</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.test1').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('#test1-content').show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        $('#test1-content').hover(function () {

        }, function () {
            $('.test1').removeClass("active");
            $(this).hide("slide", {
                direction: "right"
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
    $('.test2').hover(function () {
        $('#test2-content').show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        $('#test2-content').hide("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('.test3').hover(function () {
        $('#test3-content').show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        $('#test3-content').hide("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

function hideOther(){
    $(".menu-item").each(function(){
        var id= $(this).attr("id");
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            return $("#"+id+"-content").hide("slide", {
                direction: "right"
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}

$(".menu-item").each(function(){
    //get menu item's id
    var id= $(this).attr("id");

    //attach hover handler
    $(this).hover(function(){
        hideOther();
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#"+id+"-content").show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    }, function(){
       //we are taking care of removing others 
       //already.
    });
});

});
```

here's a jsfiddle that does somewhat what you want: 
http://jsfiddle.net/K5P9Z/109/

basically instead of trying to deal with each menu item's hover handler individually, it's better to come up with a generic solution. having said that, you can definitely improve this fiddle by adding delays in hover handlers activation and using promises (http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

I'll leave it for you to enjoy the exploration of these topics though :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed all of the hover functions except the first, then spiffed it up (there were some minor bracket issues), then copied the whole thing and changed it to test2, etc. I think you can do it for the third one.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K5P9Z/110/)

JS (first one only)

```
$('.test1').hover(function () {
                               $(this).addClass("active");
                               $('#test1-content').show("slide", {
                                                                  direction: "right"
                                                                  },
                                                                  1000 );
                               },
                               function () {
                                   $('#test1-content').hover( function(){},
                                                              function(){
                                                                         $('.test1').removeClass("active");
                                                                         $(this).hide("slide", {
                                                                                                direction: "right"
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                1000);
                                                                                                }

                                                             );
                                            }
                   );
```